# How can I change the icons of the application?

Tags: android

I want to change icons of the my application. I have created a 40x40 icon for this reason. But, I do not know how I can do that ? How can I change the icons of the application ?

And,  How can I change the background image of the application ?

Comment: Please accept an anwser if it solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

Go to `AndroidManifest.xml`, you will see this:

```
 android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
```

If you copy your own image to `/res/drawable` replace the standard icon. If you want to replace other images (wich are located in your code) you can do the same, first copy the image to `/res/drawable` and then replace the old image name with the new one.

Answer (score 0):

You place your images in the res folders. Just copy and paste it. You can replace the current image by removing it and renaming your image to it's name. Otherwise jsut call the new image from the code

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/icons-launcher.html) online tool is very helpful in generated icons for different screen densities.

Once you've made the icon, just download it and put the icon in each drawable-X folder from the downloaded file into the corresponding folder in your project.

Then add `android:icon="@drawable/filename"` to your `<application>` tag.

For the application background, put the background image in your drawable folders in the required sizes, and then add `android:background="@drawable/backgroundname"` to the root layout of the Activity.

Other than that, if you prefer to manually resize your icons, here are the sizes for different densities (from [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_launcher.html)).

```
ldpi (120 dpi) - 36 x 36 px
mdpi (160 dpi) - 48 x 48 px
hdpi (240 dpi) - 72 x 72 px
xhdpi (320 dpi) - 96 x 96 px
```